# Removing Python overhead when wrapping C++ vectors

Tags: vector, cython

```
from libcpp.algorithm cimport sort as stdsort
from libcpp.algorithm cimport unique
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
# from libcpp cimport bool
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.initializedcheck(False)
cdef class Vector:
    cdef vector[cython.int] wrapped_vector

    # the easiest thing to do is add short wrappers for the methods you need
    def push_back(self, int num):
        self.wrapped_vector.push_back(num)

    def sort(self):
        stdsort(self.wrapped_vector.begin(), self.wrapped_vector.end())

    def unique(self):
        self.wrapped_vector.erase(unique(self.wrapped_vector.begin(), self.wrapped_vector.end()), self.wrapped_vector.end())


    def __str__(self):
        return "[" + ", ".join([str(i) for i in self.wrapped_vector]) + "]"

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.wrapped_vector.size()

    @cython.boundscheck(False)
    @cython.wraparound(False)
    @cython.initializedcheck(False)
    def __setitem__(self, int key, int item):
        self.wrapped_vector[key] = item

    @cython.boundscheck(False)
    @cython.wraparound(False)
    @cython.initializedcheck(False)
    def __getitem__(self, int key):
        return self.wrapped_vector[key]
```

I have tried to wrap vectors so that I can use them in Python dicts.

This seems to create crazy amounts of overhead. See line 72 and 75 for example. They just add an integer to the number already in the vector:

[image]

Is it possible to remove this overhead or is this the price I pay to wrap vectors?

Comment: You are creating a Python object, a dictionary. But by the way, it looks like this just produces `tags` for the last file, throwing away the results for the previous reads.

Comment: Yes, the logic of the code is not important yet, but good catch :)

Comment: Where am I creating a Python dict though?

Comment: What does `add_reads_to_dict` do?  I see several uses of `tags.values()` and `tags.items()`, Python dictionary methods.

Comment: Sorry! Important info. add_reads_to_dict creates a dict of vectors. So the `v`s above are vectors :)

Comment: And the lines involving just `v` are a paler yellow, indicating less overhead.  I was focusing on the bright yellow lines.  Did you expand those lines, 72, 75, 78 to see what they are doing?

Comment: As long as you use def-functions you will get the overhead of creating python-objects. You either have to use the cdef-Versions of functions or vectorize your operations - similar to numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be based on [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34300002/4657412). The purpose of adding `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` to the `cdef class Vector` is purely so that it can be indexed from Python. From Cython you can index into the C++ vector directly for extra speed.

At the start of your `files_to_bins` add the line:

```
cdef Vector v
```

This will get Cython to make sure that anything assigned to `v` is a `Vector` object (it'll raise a `TypeError` if not) and thus you'll be allowed to access its `cdef` attributes directly.

Then change the line:

```
v[i] = v[i] + half_fragment_size
```

to:

```
v.wrapped_vector[i] = v.wrapped_vector[i] + half_fragment_size
```

(and similarly for the other indexing lines)

---

Be aware that `boundscheck(False)` and `wraparound(False)` is doing **absolutely nothing** for C++ objects. The C++ indexing operator performs no bounds checking (and Cython doesn't add it in) and it does not support negative indexing either. `boundscheck` and `wraparound` only apply to indexing memoryviews or numpy arrays.