# Calling Cython from c++ with not built-in types

Tags: c++, cython

I'm trying to extend functionality of my lib written in C++ with Python and Cython. I have class MyClass in C++ which is essential for my lib. And I'm using a lot it's wrapper class PyMyClass in Python. So I want to use functions (with PyMyClass as argument) from C++. How I can accomplish this?

I imagine it something like this:

```
cdef public my_func(MyClass class):
     *cast MyClass to PyMyClass*
     other_py_func(PyMyClass)
```

myclass.h

```
namespace classes {
    class MyClass
    {

    public:
        explicit MyClass(int x, int y);
        int sum();
    private:
        int a;
        int b;
    };
}
```

myclass.cpp

```
MyClass::MyClass(int x, int y)
{
    a = x;
    b = y;
}

MyClass::sum()
{
    return a + b
}
```

pymyclass.pyx

```
cdef extern from "myclass.h" namespace "classes":
    cdef cppclass MyClass:
        MyClass(int x, int y) except +
        int sum()

    cdef public my_func(MyClass var):
         print "It is python"
```

cdef class PyMyClass(object):
cdef MyClass *c_class

```
    def __cinit__(self, int x, int y):
        self.c_class = new MyClass(x,y)

   def __dealoc__(self):
       del self.c_class.sum()

    def sum(self):
        return self.c_class.sum()
```

I understand that I can add get_x(), get_y() and set_x(int), set_y(int) to MyClass and just copy all the fields from MyClass to PyMyClass. But PyMyClass has already a pointer to MyClass. Is it possible just assign address of MyClass instance to PyMyClass field? I mean something like this:

```
cdef class PyMyClass(object):
       cdef MyClass *c_class
    
       def __cinit__(self, int x, int y):
            self.c_class = MyClass(x,y)

       def __cinit__(self, void * ptr):
           self.c_class = (Antenna *)ptr
    
       def __dealoc__(self):
           del self.c_class.sum()

       def sum(self):
            return self.c_class.sum()
```

Then Cython function will look like
cdef public my_func(MyClass *class):
pyclass = PyMyClass(class)
other_py_func(pyclass)

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. _Is it possible to just put it in?_ Put what in? Where? Are you trying to call PyMyClass from Python? How would it be called? Are you instead trying to call Cython built PyMyClass from C++?

Comment: @danny, i've edited question. Hope now it more specific

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677231/how-to-expose-a-function-returning-a-c-object-to-python-without-copying-the-ob/33679481#33679481

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a Cython extension class from existing C++ pointer, use a factory function.

For example:

```
cdef class PyMyClass:
   cdef MyClass *c_class

   def __cinit__(self):
        # Set pointer to null on object init
        self.c_class = NULL

   def __dealoc__(self):
       if self.c_class is not NULL:
           del self.c_class

   def sum(self):
        return self.c_class.sum()

cdef object PyMyClass_factory(MyClass *ptr):
    cdef PyMyClass py_obj = PyMyClass()
    # Set extension pointer to existing C++ class ptr
    py_obj.c_class = ptr
    return py_obj
```

That gives you access to the C++ class via its pointer without copying or moving any data. `PyMyClass_factory` can be used anywhere you want to return a Python `PyMyClass` object from an existing C++ pointer.

Note that Python does not support function overloading (nor Cython) so you cannot have two `__cinit__` signatures, one with no arguments and one that creates a new C++ class from two integers.

If you want to create a new C++ class via Cython, a new factory function to do that is needed as per above example.

It would look like:

```
cdef object PyMyClass_factory_new(int x, int y):
    cdef MyClass cpp_obj = new MyClass(x, y)
    cdef PyMyClass py_obj = PyMyClass()
    py_obj.c_class = &cpp_obj
    return py_obj
```

Also, the `cdef public my_func(MyClass var)` is not needed. `public` is for making Cython functions available to C/C++, it does not mean the same thing it does in C++. If you do not intend to use `my_func` outside Python/Cython, `public` is not needed.

If you intend to use that function via Python then it must be `def` or `cpdef`, not `cdef`.

Finally, you probably want to define the external definition as `nogil` and use `with nogil` when calling C++ functions, for obvious reasons. For example,

```
cdef extern from "myclass.h" namespace "classes" nogil:
    <..>

cdef class PyMyClass:
    <..>

    def sum(self):
        cdef int ret
        with nogil:
            ret = self.c_class.sum()
        return ret
```

Comment: Great! That is exactly that i needed!

Comment: Yes, defined my_func as public because i want to use it from C++ to have access to Python functions. And do you know why i get an error "Cannot convert 'MyClass *' to Python object" if i define PyMyClass_factory in different .pyx file? Even if  i copy all c++ MyClass declarations from pymyclass.pyx

Comment: You should put the definition in a pxd file and cimport it. The error you're getting is because it doesn't know the definition of PyMyClass_factory and so assumes that it's a standard Python function.